# Custom exit code in Kivy Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy

I am working on a Kivy app on a Raspberry Pi, and am trying to implement an update feature. Basically, the app is started inside a loop in a shell script and then depending on what the Kivy app exit code is, the shell script will execute the proper command.

What I can't figure out is how to return a custom exit code from a Kivy app to the shell script/console. I already know how to use `App.get_running_app().stop()` to simply shut it down, but I can't find anywhere in the documentation what I could pass in to set those parameters.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
class MyApp(App):
    def on_stop(self):
        sys.exit(0)
```

Can't test it here ...

Comment: That worked perfect! Specifically, I called it after `App.get_running_app().stop()` and it shut down and returned the code as desired.